# Некорректное хранение Base64 кода фотографии в БД MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Я создаю сайт,в котором каждому пользователю присваивается его фотография.

Делается это следующим образом. Человек заходит на сайт и регистрируется. На сайте присутствует область,где можно делать снимки с веб-камеры,для этого используется объект `canvas` с `src` равным base64-коду фотографии. По нажатию кнопки php передает этот `src`(разумеется, распарсенный) в таблицу.

И проблема в том,что при попытке декодирования и затем открытия изображения я получаю ошибку,что файл поврежден или слишком большой
Я создал поле ввода текста и перед отправкой base64 код пишу туда. При декодировании base64 кода из текстового поля проблем не возникает. 
Также заметил, что длина base64 кодов в тестовом поле и в таблице отличаются. 
В таблице использую формат `LongText` или `MediumText`,так как изображение большое(пробовал и с маленькими, результат тот же), кодировка `ascii`
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: а без записи в БД получается сразу полученную строку base64_decode ?

Comment: Нужно посмотреть код которым вы записываете в БД. Подозреваю что вы не экранируете base64.

Comment: Хотя вроде не обязательно экранировать... В общем ждем кода.

Comment: @DmitryV. Разобрался почему возникает ошибка. В текстовой строке присутствуют знаки "+",а в таблице MySQL "+" заменяется на пробел(" ") Как избежать подобной ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт,обрабатываю строку с пробелами в php,заменяя пробелы на знаки "+"

Comment: Формат ответа странный, но это вполне нормальный ответ.